# Send command line arguments via ssh

Tags: ssh, kodi

Hi I have a remote RPI4 running raspbian.
I would like to start Kodi with the --pulse argument to enable bluetooth.
If I open terminal and type
Kodi --pulse
Then Kodi starts with the pulse enabled and the speakers work
If I SSH into the RPI and use the SSH command
Kodi --pulse then Kodi starts but no pulse and no speakers
How do I send the --pulse part across ssh?
Thanks